# Sitecore Items are not installed correctly with Sitecore TDS package Installer

Tags: installation, tds, packages, itemservice

Our application is on Sitecore 8.2 Update 7 with TDS 5.8

We install TDS packages using TDS Package Installer

`function doCustomContentManagementInstall() {
 param (
 [string]$siteName,
 [string]$downloadsFolder
 )
 try { 
 writeLog -msg ("Installing content update")
 &"C:\Software\TDS\PackageInstaller.exe" -v -sitecoreUrl "https://$siteName" -sitecoreDeployFolder "C:\Software\TDSDummyFolder" -packagePath "$websiteDirectory\master.update" /quiet
 writeLog -msg ("Installing content-deployment update")
 &"C:\Software\TDS\PackageInstaller.exe" -v -sitecoreUrl "https://$siteName" -sitecoreDeployFolder "C:\Software\TDSDummyFolder" -packagePath "$websiteDirectory\content-deployment.update" /quiet
 }
 catch { 
 writeLog("Failed on doCustomContentManagementInstall")
 writeLog -msg ($_.Exception)
 }
}`

The newly added content Items do not seem to be installed correctly on the server , the content Items are duplicated one with the correct Template type(correct), another of type Sitecore/Templates/System/Node (incorrect)

[image]

I have tried installing the .update package manually using the UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx, everything seems to be working as expected , i do not face this issue

Any pointers on why this could be happening would be great , than